# How to add a linebreak using REG command in a MULTI_SZ value type?

Tags: batch-file, cmd, registry, registrykey

How I can insert a newline using REG command in a MULTI SZ value?

This is what I've tried:

```
REG ADD "HKCU\Test" /V "Test Multi SZ" /T "REG_MULTI_SZ" /D "a\n b" /F
```

..But this is what I got:

[image]

http://img14.imageshack.us/img14/3038/grxd.jpg

[image]

> This is what I want to reproduce using REG.exe:

The key:

[image]

[image]

Binary data:

[image]

The Regedit script:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Test]
"Test Multi SZ"=hex(7):61,00,00,00,62,00,00,00,00,00
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this, line separator is `\0`:

```
reg add HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Test /t REG_MULTI_SZ /v "Test Multi SZ" /d "a\0b\0"
```

Enter `reg add /?` for help at the command line.

---

Example:

```
reg add HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Test /t REG_MULTI_SZ /v "Test Multi SZ" /d "red\0green\0blue\0dark grey\0"
```

```
reg query HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Test

HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Test
    Test Multi SZ       REG_MULTI_SZ    red\0green\0blue\0dark grey\0\0
```

Screenshots from `regedit`:

- main window
  [image: main window]
- edit binary window
  [image: edit binary window]
- edit multiline window
  [image: edit multiline window]

Comment: +1 This is documented in the help to the `add` subcommand (`reg add /?`).

Comment: @Endoro thanks, I've never noticed that was documented in the command help.

Answer (score 1):

Try with hex values - it should be `0d 0a`